# 'No available video device' error in pygame on vs code

Tags: python, pygame

So I am getting started with learning pygame and running the following code:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pg.display.set_caption("First Game")
x = 50
y = 50
height = 60
width = 30
vel = 10

run = True
while run:
    pg.time.delay(100)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

pg.quit()
```

While trying to execute this via terminal, I am getting an error as "No available video device".
How do I resolve this error?
I am running Python 3.7.6, pygame 1.9.6 on VS Code, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Please run this

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()

width = 700
height = 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

def redrawWindow():
    win.fill((128, 128, 128))
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    redrawWindow()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            exit()
    pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Comment: the problem still persists.